# Passing FixedArrays and Bytes to smart contract

Tags: rust, ethereum, smartcontracts

I am having some issues with passing a 2 x 2 matrix to a function using the [web3](https://docs.rs/web3/0.10.0/web3/) library.

The library is meant to pass parameters to an ABI (Abstract Binary Interface) which calls a smart contract on a blockchain. The issue is that the ABI has certain types the parameters have to match (e.g. `Uint`, `String`).

https://docs.rs/web3/0.10.0/web3/contract/struct.Contract.html#method.call

The interface it exposes is another library called ethabi, which provides the types I need (e.g. `Bytes`, `FixedArray`)

Unfortunately, the method call needs the parameters to implement the  [`Tokenizable`](https://docs.rs/web3/0.10.0/web3/contract/tokens/trait.Tokenizable.html) trait, which `Bytes` and `FixedArray` do not.

When I try to pass strings, I get an [`AbiError(InvalidData)`](https://docs.rs/ethabi/12.0.0/ethabi/enum.Error.html), which points to a mismatch between the data I am passing the the ABI.

When I try to pass `ethabi::Token::{Bytes,FixedArrays}`, I get an error saying the `Tokenize` trait bound is not satisfied.

How can I get this?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
extern crate ethabi;
extern crate primitive_types;
extern crate web3;

use ethabi::Token::{FixedArray, FixedBytes, Uint};
use ethabi::*;
use primitive_types::*;
use web3::contract::{Contract, Options};
use web3::futures::Future;
use web3::types::{Address, Bytes, H256 as H256_w, U256 as U256_w};


fn main() {
    let addr = "*snip*";
    let smart_contract_addr = "*snip*";

    let (_eloop, transport) = web3::transports::Http::new(&addr).unwrap();

    let web3 = web3::Web3::new(transport);
    let accounts = web3.eth().accounts().wait().unwrap();

    // Accessing existing contract
    let accounts = web3.eth().accounts().wait().unwrap();

    let contract_address: Address = "83249c2366a34cCbe6b2AeFEeF94A59beFc4C4Cd".parse().unwrap();
    let contract = Contract::from_json(
        web3.eth(),
        contract_address,
        include_bytes!("../build/*snip*.abi"),
    )
    .unwrap();

    let a = Token::Uint(
        U256::from_dec_str(
            "1368015179489954701390400359078579693043519447331113978918064868415326638035",
        )
        .unwrap(),
    );
    let b = Token::Uint(
        U256::from_dec_str(
            "9918110051302171585080402603319702774565515993150576347155970296011118125764",
        )
        .unwrap(),
    );
    let c = Token::Uint(
        U256::from_dec_str(
            "4503322228978077916651710446042370109107355802721800704639343137502100212473",
        )
        .unwrap(),
    );
    let d = Token::Uint(
        U256::from_dec_str(
            "6132642251294427119375180147349983541569387941788025780665104001559216576968",
        )
        .unwrap(),
    );

    let f = vec![c, d];
    let g = vec![a, b];
    let x = FixedArray(f); /*Desired Type: https://docs.rs/ethabi/12.0.0/ethabi/enum.Token.html#method.to_array*/

    let n = Bytes::from("0xdf32340000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
    let result = contract.call(
        "calculate_aggregate",
        (x, n),
        accounts[0],
        Options::default(),
    );
    let aggregate = result.wait().unwrap();
    println!("{}", aggregate);

    /*

    Error:  the trait `web3::contract::tokens::Tokenizable` is not implemented for `ethabi::Token`
    When strings are used; thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Abi(InvalidData)', src/main.rs:115:21
    */
}
```

### Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
web3 = { git = "https://github.com/tomusdrw/rust-web3" }
ethabi = "12.0.0"
primitive-types = "0.7.0"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Comment: So how did you solve it?